# Buddypress: New Tab and Page (Members Profile)

Tags: customization, menus, buddypress

I want to add some pages/tabs to the user's buddypress profile.

I'm using the following function to get at least one page working:

```
function my_bp_nav_adder() {
    global $bp;
    bp_core_new_nav_item(
            array(
                    'name'                => __( 'Listings', 'buddypress' ),
                    'slug'                => 'my-listings',
                    'position'            => 1,
                    'screen_function'     => 'listingsdisplay',
                    'default_subnav_slug' => 'my-listings',
                    'parent_url'          => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->slug . '/',
                    'parent_slug'         => $bp->slug
            ) );
}

function listingsdisplay() {
    //add title and content here - last is to call the members plugin.php template
    add_action( 'bp_template_title', 'my_groups_page_function_to_show_screen_title' );
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'my_groups_page_function_to_show_screen_content' );
    bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/plugins' ) );
}

function my_groups_page_function_to_show_screen_title() {
    echo 'My new Page Title';
}

function my_groups_page_function_to_show_screen_content() {
    echo 'My Tab content here';

}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'my_bp_nav_adder', 50 );
```

[(found here)](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/buddypress-adding-custom-page-tab)

But if I rename `my-listings`, I get a "404 page not found".
I would like to have this called "Bookmarks"

And how can I create more pages and menu tab items by using this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
'parent_url'    => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->slug . '/',
'parent_slug'   => $bp->slug
```

to:

```
'parent_url'    => $bp->displayed_user->domain,
'parent_slug'   => $bp->profile->slug,
```

If you add another nav item, be sure to adjust *all* the fields and add new functions to handle the display.